# Opening an url in the background of an android app

Tags: android

I want to build an app to open a link in the background. Opening this link will cause my light to turn on (or anything else I might connect to it).

I got to the point where pressing a button causes the page to open, but now I would like to only let that page open in the background, so that you don't actually see it opening. Is that possible with this setup or do I need to change it completly, like into a webview or something?

I'm pretty new to programming, I have made some things, but not a lot. I'm using Android Studio, by the way.

This is the code that I have in my MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button bt1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://192.168.2.5/?pin=AAN";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a http component like HttpUrlConnection to GET that page.